# Error 500, making MYSQL connection with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to build a simple dropdown form and place the submissions in my database so I can check the results later.

Whenever, when I'm submitting the form with the submit button, nothing happens. The page just stays the same...

Chrome Console gives back an error 500 issue. What's the thing I'm doing wrong, cause I'm currently losing it. ;-)

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>V1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="">

    <label >I'm feeling...</label>

        <select name="subject_names">
            <option value="Angry">Angry</option>
            <option value="Anxious">Anxious</option>
            <option value="Bored">Bored</option>
            <option value="Cranky">Cranky</option>
            <option value="Crappy">Crappy</option>
            <option value="Depressed">Depressed</option>
            <option value="Energetic">Energetic</option>
            <option value="Exhausted">Exhausted</option>
            <option value="Frustrated">Frustrated</option>
            <option value="Happy">Happy</option>
            <option value="Motivated">Motivated</option>
            <option value="Okay">Okay</option>
            <option value="Relaxed">Relaxed</option>
            <option value="Sad">Stressed</option>
            <option value="Lazy">Lazy</option>
        </select>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

 //Including dbconfig file.
include 'db-connect.php';

$subjectName=$_POST["feeling"];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO thefeels VALUES ('$feeling')"); 

echo " Added Successfully ";

}

 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

db-connect.php:

```
$hostname = "localhost";

$username = "USERNAME";

$password = "PASSWORD";

$dbname = "DBNAME";

 $conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

 if (!$conn)

 {

 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

 }

 mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);


?>
```

Comment: *Stop*  using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. if you use php if you use an newer php version the API is already removedAlso 500 is an internal Server error. Look into the Server logfiles for more informations

Comment: Your first problem is using the `mysql_*` functions. Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure - they have been removed entirely from modern versions of PHP (version 7.0 and higher). Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. Beyond that, check your `error_log` for details about the error.

Comment: In addition to the above - **that you should not use `mysql_` and that you should use a prepared statement** -. you have not defined `$feeling` anywhere, and the variable `$subjectName` is using the wrong index in the POST array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing a POST value that isn't set:

```
$subjectName=$_POST["feeling"];
```

You probably want:

```
$subjectName=$_POST["subject_names"];
```

You should stop using mysql_query though. It's deprecated and was removed in PHP7. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Edit: Error 500 can be caused by bad file permissions, for example. Did you check the permissions?

Comment: Ah yeah, that one wasn't correct, but even after making the change I'm still getting the 500 error...

Comment: This would be a warning or notice, not a result of 500 error;

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right @SimosFasouliotis . From my experience, 500 errors are often caused by bad file permissions, e.g. by giving `chmod 777` to them and then trying to open them via browser.